# Check if value exists in database

Tags: php, mysql, return-value

I'm trying a code that checks whether the value exists in database or not.My code is:

```
$registration_code = $_POST['registration_code'];
$registration_code = mysql_real_escape_string($registration_code);
$checkcustomer = mysql_query("SELECT `customer_no` FROM customer WHERE registration_code = '$registration_code'");
echo $checkcustomer;
if (!$checkcustomer) {
echo "<script language=javascript>alert('Please enter a valid Registration code.')</script>";   
}
else{
    // some php code
}
```

Instead of returning customer no. ,my query returns 'Resource id #19'  when i echo `$checkcustomer`.Can someone help me????

Comment: Please read the manual of functions you are using.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **mysql_fetch_array**  to extract data

```
$registration_code = $_POST['registration_code'];

$registration_code = mysql_real_escape_string($registration_code);
$checkcustomer = mysql_query("SELECT `customer_no` FROM customer WHERE registration_code = '$registration_code'");

$val = mysql_fetch_array($checkcustomer);
echo $val;
if (!$val) {
echo "<script language=javascript>alert('Please enter a valid Registration code.')</script>";   
}
else{
    // some php cpde
}
```

by the way, don't use **mysql_**  function, they're deprecated and are no longer maintained. Use PDO or **mysqli**  functions.

Comment: Facepalm!I feel stupid!Works perfectly now.....

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PDO instead of the deprecated MySql Functions.
Also be aware that using mysql_real_escape_string can lead to mysql-injection.

To make your code work you should use

```
$result = mysql_query('your query');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['customer_no'];
}
```

Comment: just search for: mysql_real_escape_string sql-injection you will find multiple examples that show injections that work with code that uses mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: good point, I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just use `mysql_num_rows`

```
if (mysql_num_rows($checkcustomer)) {
   echo "<script language=javascript>alert('Please enter a valid Registration code.')</script>";   
} else{
   // some php code
}
```

**Note:** `mysql_*` functions deprecated. the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this...

```
if(mysql_num_rows($checkcustomer) == 0) {
    //do something
} else { 
    //do something else
}
```

it will basically check how many rows have been returned

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['customer_no'];
```

or if you just want to check whether record exist or not then check for

```
mysql_num_rows
```